# ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for '#sql-5dd9_ac7bc' doesn't have this option

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Here is the table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `a` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    
  `c` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    
  `d` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '259200',    
  `e` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ascii',    
  `f` text,    
  `g` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `h` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `i` datetime DEFAULT NULL,    
  `j` datetime DEFAULT NULL,    
  `k` datetime DEFAULT NULL,    
  `l` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `m` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',    
  `n` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)    
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ENCRYPTION='Y'
```

And error occurs when adding column:

```
alter table table_1 add req_user varchar(20) default NULL;
```

> ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for '#sql-5dd9_ac7bc' doesn't have this option

Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Which MySQL Version?

Comment: Version is 5.7.20

Comment: I find a question that I cannot successfully when adding column in table ENGINE=MyISAM and ENCRYPTION = 'Y'. How to handle adding column without change these settings?